# Labview - Locate pixel of determined color

Tags: labview

I am trying to find out how to locate the pixel of determined color.
I have a binary picture. The whole picture is black and there is a white pixel at the first line of image somewhere. 
I need to define the coordinates of the white pixel (such as [0;x]) and crop the picture by x-coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by transforming the picture into a 2D array, retrieving the first array and using the search 1D array method. See VI snippet below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much!
But I still can't locate the pixel. The result of this manipulation is "-1".

Comment: UPD: works fine after replacing "true" to "0" and changing type of pixmap to 8bit

Comment: Either you image is to blame or there is some miscommunication, I tested the code with a tiny image and it worked as expected. Can you test the given solution with a 2D boolean array. If that works compare it to the 2D boolean array you get from the image. You can also make a tiny image to test the code. Be sure to check if the line you want is read out (instead of the collumn).

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is in image. Because I have 8-bit picture, not a binary. But I've found the solution with you help.  Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can read the pixel colors into a 2D array easily enough. Use the "Array Index" to pull the zeroth row off it (wire a zero to the rows index and leave the column index unwired). Then run a For Loop indexing that row. Turn on the conditional stop on the For Loop (it's in the right-click menu). Stop when the pixel is white, and wire the value of the [i] terminal out through the tunnel.